# Ajax запрос в Laravel

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, laravel

Указываю url:

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/add_to_cart",
        data: {"product": product},
        success: function (result) {
            console.log(result);
        }
    })
```

Указываю его в роуте:

```
Route::post('/add_to_cart', 'AjaxController@addProduct');
```

Получаю:

```
MethodNotAllowedHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 218:
```

Подскажите как правильно указывать url в AJAX или что я сделал не так?

Comment: |        | POST     | add_to_cart            |          | App\Http\Controllers\AjaxController@addProduct

Answer (score 1):

Помимо добавления метода необходимо еще отправлять токен с каждым запросом.
P.S. Не претендую на лучший ответ. Но у меня работало. Надеюсь и Вам поможет.

```
$.ajax(
{
    type: 'post',
    url: '/add_to_cart',
    data: {_token:"{{ csrf_token() }}", product: product},
    beforeSend: function()
    {
        ...
    },
    success: function(data)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Я пробовал отправлять - не выходит. При этом я уже использовал ajax на других страницах, но там js код на одной странице с вёрсткой. И токен отправлялся без проблем и всё работает. Тут же у меня вёрстка отдельно от JS кода.

Answer (score 0):

Ошибка оказалась настолько тупой, что мне стыдно.
Вообщем, проблема была в том, что я поместил метод в php файле за пределами класса. Потому была ошибка 500, ибо такого метода в классе не существовало. Спасибо всем за помощь